# postAttachCommand is never called in my devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file's content:

```
{
    "name": "CustomersApi",
    "image": "company/api:latest",
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
            "bash": {
                "path": "bash"
            }
        }
    },
    "remoteUser": "root",
    "mounts": [
        "source=customersapi,target=/root/.vscode-server/extensions,type=volume"
    ],
    "postAttachCommand": "mkdir -p /RandomDirectory"
}
```

As you can see I simply create a `/RandomDirectory` inside the container and I'm the root user.

But this command never runs. And I see no logs whatsoever when I attach to a container.

What can be wrong here?